# Create Widgets for specific fields of a feature

Tags: pyqgis, pyqgis-3

I need to create a widget were some fields of a feature are listed and are editable.

I used QgsAttributeForm for this, but this widget is too big and has to many fields.

I need to provide a QCheckBox as well before every field to mark it as selected or deselected.

I took a look at the QgsFeature class and its fields() method. The QgsField class has a type() Method for determing the type of a field, but unfortunately I have not yet found an easy to create a widget from a field type.

I took a look at the QgsFieldWrapper classes, but they don't seem to work in PyQGIS because they are abstract classes.

Is there an easy way to create a default widget from a feature field, e.g. 
widget = FieldWidgetWrapper(field)
that I can use to generate these controls?

I know I can create custom UIs for AttributeForms, but this will not work, because I need to be able to have more than one feature in this widget represented by specific fields.

[image: Example]

Currently I display everything in LineEdits, but this is not working, especially for DateTime objects. It would be cool if the widgets can be created automatically from a field like in the QgsAttributeForm class...

Answer (score 2):

Ok I managed to create a Widget now, but I'm unable to add it to a layout.
I created this test code:

```
reg: QgsEditorWidgetRegistry = QgsGui.editorWidgetRegistry()
w = QWidget()
layout = QVBoxLayout()
layout.addWidget(QPushButton('Test'))

fldIdx = fields.lookupField('nummer')
if fldIdx < fields.count() and fldIdx >= 0:
    widgetSetup: QgsEditorWidgetSetup = reg.findBest(flurstueckLayer, 'nummer')
    eww = reg.create(widgetSetup.type(), flurstueckLayer, fldIdx, widgetSetup.config(), None, w)
    eww.setFeature(feat)
    formWidget = QgsAttributeFormEditorWidget(eww, widgetSetup.type(), None)
    formWidget.setMode(QgsAttributeFormWidget.DefaultMode)
    layout.addWidget(formWidget)

w.setLayout(layout)
w.show()
```

it renders the widget and also adds the value form the feature attribute, but it is not managed by my QVBoxLayout():

[image]

I also tried to add the form to the layout (formWidget.form()), but it also doesn't work.

Am I using the correct classes and methods?
I took this code from the AttributeForm C++ code.

How can I add this to my layout so it will be correctly displayed?

Comment: When I set the Mode to Search: formWidget.setMode(QgsAttributeFormWidget.SearchMode), I can see a searchWidget-Combobox, which is embedded correctly in the layout. The editor still is not added to the layout.